# Contenido de un tar.gz con nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo un archivo `.tar.gz`, el cual tengo que descomprimir en una ruta , pero necesito revisar lo que esta dentro de el para después descomprimirlo. tengo el siguiente código:

```
const targz = require('targz');

targz.decompress({
    src: 'archivo.tar.gz',
    dest: 'ruta' //ruta donde se realiza la descompresión ...
}, function(err){
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Done!");
    }
});
```

Como yo podría revisar lo que contiene el `tar.gz` antes que se descomprima, por ejemplo que dentro aya un archivo **texto.txt** , y que yo pueda leer ese fichero de dentro y en dependencia de lo que diga, descomprimo o no. Gracias de antemano

Comment: haz intentado recorrer la ruta luego de la descompresion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cómo estás?

Se me ocurre lo siguiente:

1 - Puedes utilizar el siguiente módulo para ejecutar CMD en el servidor como muestra la documentación de dicho módulo: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-command-line

2 - Tomando el primer punto en cuenta, puedes ejecutar comando en consola con el que podrás extraer un archivo espeficico dentro de un tar.gz con el siguiente comando:

```
tar -zxvf <tar filename> <file you want to extract>
```

3 - Luego de extraer el archivo que necesitas lo puedes leer para ver que haces a continuación.

Recuerda manejar bien los callbacks para esperar descomprima el archivo y poder leerle.

Un saludo y nos cuentas cómo te fue.

Comment: no usare el node-command-line , por que estoy utilizando shelljs para correr comandos a la consola, pero esa es la idea que no se me ocurría, gracias

Comment: Excelente!

Saludos!